# How to show Multiple Pins on mkmapview

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

I want to show multiple pin annotations on a mapview.

I am getting multiple hotel location lat long from server and i have store them in `NSMutableArray`, now I want to show these lat long value on my mapview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a model object that conforms to the [MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. At the very least, it should implement the `coordinate` method (which returns a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` struct for your latitude and longitude). If you want to display a callout for the map pin, you'll also need to implement the `title` method.

You should create one of these objects for each lat,lon pair, and store these in your array. Then call the `addAnnotations:` on your mapView with the array of objects

Answer (score 2):

Every thing you need is here: [MKMApView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205) and here [MKAnnotations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKAnnotation)

Some a nice example code: [WeatherMap](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009491)